# xpath with simplexml not able to access nested element

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml like so:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <foo SeqNum="1">
    <bar>1234</bar>
  </foo>
  <foo SeqNum="20">
    <bar>6789</bar>
  </foo>
```

and I'm trying to get the value `6789` with this query:

```
$xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <foo SeqNum="1">
    <bar>1234</bar>
  </foo>
  <foo SeqNum="20">
    <bar>6789</bar>
  </foo>";
$simple = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$result = $simple->xpath('//*[@SeqNum="20"]/bar/'); // result gives me nothing
```

So I tried to just get the parent like so

```
$result = $simple->xpath('//*[@SeqNum="20"]')[0]->asXML();
```

which gives me:

```
  <foo SeqNum="20">
    <bar>6789</bar>
  </foo>
```

So I'm almost there but am really stuck about what I'm not understanding. Thank you!

Comment: Try without the trailing `/`. Be aware that valid XML needs an document element.

Comment: @ThW thank you. I just tried it to no avail.

Comment: Demo, fixed https://3v4l.org/UrSV0

Comment: thanks! I just realized that my example wasn't complete and didn't include the defined namespace. It looks like I needed to register the namespace to perform any queries on the xml. When I have a moment, I'll fix the example up. Thank you so much and feel free to post the solution as a solution and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Yes, you will have to register the namespace on any SimpleXMLElement instance that you call the `xpath()` method on. It is less code with `DOMXpath::evaluate()` actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are several mistakes in the question. The XML needs a root element and the trailing `/` breaks the expression. The literal quotes need to be changed to single quotes (or all the inner double quotes need to be escaped.)

Fixed example:

```php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <foo SeqNum="1">
    <bar>1234</bar>
  </foo>
  <foo SeqNum="20">
    <bar>6789</bar>
  </foo>
</foo>';

$simple = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$result = $simple->xpath('//*[@SeqNum="20"]/bar');
var_dump((string)$result[0]);
```

Output:

```
string(4) "6789"
```

#### With Namespaces

If your XML is using namespaces you will have to define an alias/prefix for this namespace URI and use that in the Xpath expression.

```php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<p:foo xmlns:p="http://www.example.com">   
   <p:foo SeqNum="1">     
     <p:bar>1234</p:bar>   
   </p:foo>   
   <p:foo SeqNum="20">     
     <p:bar>6789</p:bar>   
   </p:foo> 
</p:foo> 
XML;
 
$simple = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$simple->registerXpathNamespace('e', 'http://www.example.com');
$result = $simple->xpath('//*[@SeqNum="20"]/e:bar');
var_dump((string)$result[0]);
```

The example uses a different alias for the expression to show that the document and the expression are separate - only the namespace URI has to match.

Namespaces have to be unique so they are defined with an URI (a superset of URL). Because that would get messy aliases are used in node names. The following 3 elements all can be read as `{http://www.example.com}bar`.

- `<p:bar xmlns:p="http://www.example.com"/>`
- `<e:bar xmlns:e="http://www.example.com"/>`
- `<bar xmlns="http://www.example.com"/>`

Comment: I had a question as to how this can be updated for a case where the xml is changed to `$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" xmlns:p="www.example.com"?>
<p:foo>
  <p:foo SeqNum="1">
    <p:bar>1234</p:bar>
  </p:foo>
  <p:foo SeqNum="20">
    <p:bar>6789</p:bar>
  </p:foo>
</p:foo>
XML;` thanks again!

Comment: I added an example with a namespace.